# Need help regarding aurora DB scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-aurora

I need to scale the Aurora DB up and then back down at later sometime but I dont need any downtime not even a bit. I though of doing it by creating aurora replica and promoting it then scaling primary and promoting back to primary. But this involve downtime. Please suggest any alternative way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would first ask you in what sense do you need to scale up? writing? reading? if you currently run a server with a high-read/low-write ratio, i'd suggest another read-replica (or more) and then configure your application specifically to use the read replica in those specific cases where you're only making queries and *not* modifying the data. in this sense, you're offloading your writes to a separate instance of the same data and letting the primary deal with mostly writes. if you did this, i'd also suggest spreading out the read replicas across other availability zones, in case the AZ of your primary goes down, another read-replica will be auto-promoted to primary.

armed with that info, i would suggest you scale up with read replicas that your application is configured to use, then you can bring down those replicas as you scale down without ever bringing down the Aurora primary. it's more of a configuration problem in dealing with multiple RDS endpoints, essentially.

HTH.

one caveat is that there is some delay in replication between primary and read replicas (my instances show about 10-20 milliseconds), so you have to keep this in mind if you perform a write then a read in fast succession -- if your first read after the initial write happens 'too fast', the replica might not see the change and may either see no data (if you're creating) or stale data (if you're updating).

in general, this isn't an issue until you're under some heavy load and the writes on the primary are backed up and you start reading from the read replica before the writes have been applied to the primary.

HTH.

Comment: thanks for your help. Here I would like to clear that I want to change my Primary instance type from medium to large without any downtime. 
I could use read replica and then promote it to primary and then change the instance type of my previous primary db and then promote it back to primary. But here there will be certain downtime for my application as it will take sometime for replica to become primary. So I just would like to know whether changing the instance type of aurora db is possible? if yes then how

Comment: well, i know it _is_ possible to have read replicas that are of a different service offering (amt of storage, cpu, network, etc) than the primary. i think the only important thing is that the read replica be able to store as process as much as your db traffic requires. in that way, when you want to 'scale' down without downtime, you'd (1) create 'smaller' read replica + wait till it's fully done w/ sync (2) fail over the primary (this is you can do without downtime) (3) either remove original primary or remove it and spin up another, smaller read-replica.

Comment: ^^ i forgot to mention -- one great thing about AWS is that you can just experiment for an hour and you'll be charge for an hour's worth of resources -- then spin everything down and you're not obligated to spend any more than that. an entire day of testing could be < $75, for example.